# Retrofit cancel() & check if request was delivered to server

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

**How can I be sure that calling cancel() on the Retrofit cause request is not delivered to the server?**

Currently I know, that calling cancel on the Retrofit will invoke onFailure branch of the callback. And then I can check if the cause of the failure is because call was cancelled.
https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-cancel-requests

**But can I be somehow sure, that request didn't arrive to the server?**

Comment: can you not check the status code and arrive at conclusion?. Also check https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Response.html#isSuccessful--

Answer (score 0):

Code snippet from [here](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-cancel-requests)

```
new Callback<ResponseBody>() {  
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "request success");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            if (call.isCanceled()) {
                Log.e(TAG, "request was cancelled");
            }
            else {
                Log.e(TAG, "other larger issue, i.e. no network connection?");
            }

        }
    };
```

According to that this will raise in case call was canceled, as it say

`// something happened, for example: user clicked cancel button
call.cancel();`

If you call `call.cancel()` let's say later it means you already got a response from the server, therefore you won't get to `onFailure` point where `call.isCanceled()` is being checked :)

> If you cancel the request, Retrofit will classify this as a failed request and thus call the onFailure() callback in your request declaration. This callback is also used when there is no Internet connection or something went wrong on the network level. From the app perspective, these errors are quite a bit different.

Comment: But I can't find response on my original question. When you invoke call.cancel() how you will get information if request was already sent to the server or you was quick enough and request was not sent at all?

Comment: Depends on your request, and mostly you won't be `quick enough` to cancel it unless you start the request later so user have time to cancel it. Since you get the response in `onResponse` that means he couldn't cancel it in time.

Comment: Ok thx. **Ionut J. Bejan** it seems to be true, that whenever I already start the Call, request can be delevired to the server. And if I use Call.cancel() I just dismiss listening to the response and therefore there is no way to know if I cancelled that request before it was sent or not.

Comment: Well, I think once you get to `onResponse` means your server responded, therefore means it got the request :) (that means you called `call.cancel()` too late. I think is simple as that